# Applications of differentiation

Tags: calculus, differential

Let $f$ be a twice differentiable function such that $f ^{\prime\prime}(x)=-f(x)$ and $f'(x)=g(x)$  for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. If $h(x) =[f(x)]^2+[g(x)]^2$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then find $h(10)$ if $h(5)=11$.
How can do this sum without using differential equation? Must be done using techniques restricted to Calculus 1.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @John_dydx   I am at the same place where I started ,the problem is perplexing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the derivative of $h(x) = (f(x))^2 + (g(x))^2$

$$h'(x) = 2(f(x)f'(x) + g(x)g'(x))$$

Note that $g'(x) = f^{\prime \prime}(x)= -f(x)$

The above makes $h'(x)= 0$

Using the fact that $h(5)= 11$, you should be able to finish off

Comment: Could you say in a manner that involves only calc 1 ,coz we haven't started calc 2 ,btw thanks for the answer

Comment: @user794763, I believe derivatives and integration are both covered in calculus I? https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calci/calci.aspx

Comment: Yeah but I am in loc max and min exercise ,I am yet to learn integration

Comment: @user794763, In that case, I suggest you modify your question to something like: without using integration and differentiation, find $h(10)$

Comment: Ok, could you give a solution without integration?

Comment: @user794763  "derivative of a constant function is 0 "

Answer (score 3):

We have that $f''(x)=g'(x)=-f(x)$ and $f'(x)=g(x)$. Then $$h'(x)=2f(x)f'(x)+2g(x)g'(x)$$
$$=2f(x)g(x)-2g(x)f(x)=0$$

Thus $$h'(x)=0$$

Can you end it?